# How to SUM over x identical MySQL SUM tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have 50 databases for 50 centers to document surgical procedures performed. I can count the number of these procedures per center easily:

```
SELECT
ub.Krankenhaus AS "Zentrum",
"01" AS "ZentrumID",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Keine Operation durchgeführt",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "2") AS "Gastric Banding",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "3") AS "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "4") AS "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass banded",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "5") AS "Scopinaro",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "6") AS "Duodenal Switch (DS)",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "7") AS "Sleeve Resection",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "8") AS "Gastric Pacemaker",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "9") AS "Billroth II",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "10") AS "Gastroplasty",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "11") AS "Fobi / Capella Bypass",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "12") AS "Larrad",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "13") AS "Santoro",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "14") AS "DJB",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "15") AS "TOGA",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "16") AS "Endobarrier",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "17") AS "Gastric Plication",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "18") AS "Stomaphyx",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "19") AS "Omega Loop Bypass",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "20") AS "Omega Loop Bypass banded",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "21") AS "Long Limb Bypass",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "22") AS "Distal Very Long Gastric Bypass (Thurnheer)",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "23") AS "Endoscopic Sclerosation",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "24") AS "Swedish Adjustable Gastric Bypass (SAGB)",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "25") AS "Vertical Banded Gastroplasty (VBG)",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "26") AS "Plastic Abdominal Wall Reconstruction (PAWR)",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "27") AS "Inner Hernia Repair",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "28") AS "Single Anastomosis Duodeno-Ileal Bypass with Sleeve Gastrectomy (SADI-S)",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "99") AS "Anderes OP-Verfahren",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe"

FROM ods01.dat_patient p
LEFT OUTER JOIN ods01.dat_optherapie op ON op.patID = p.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ods01.users_benutzer ub ON ub.ID = p.UserID

WHERE 1 = 1
AND op.OP1Datum BETWEEN "2019-01-01" AND "2019-12-31"
AND p.Testzwecke = 0
AND ub.ID = p.UserID
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM ods01.dat_optherapie op2
    WHERE op2.PatID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision
)
```

The result is a nice list I can layout using PHP so that I receive all surgeries in the left column row and the respective absolute number in the right one:

[image]

Using the

```
AND NOT EXIST blah
```

statement at the end of the SQL query I only allow for the latest record set revision.

Using

```
UNION ALL
```

I can combine all the 50 centers' results into such tables one after another. It takes a longer scroll to display them all but it works.

**But:**

How can I create only one resulting table with all surgeries from all 50 centers SUMmed into it (a SUM over the SUMs)?

To make things more concrete, here is the MCVE:

```
CREATE TABLE `dat_optherapie` (
    `ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `patID` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `OP1Datum` DATE NOT NULL,
    `OP1OPVerfahren` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
    `revision` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    INDEX `ix_dat_optherapie_patid` (`patID`, `ID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_german1_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=7798;
```

Here are some INSERTs:

```
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3307, 3005, '2017-06-22', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3308, 3005, '2017-06-22', 1, 3);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3960, 3005, '2017-06-22', 1, 4);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3977, 3005, '2017-06-22', 1, 5);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (4246, 3005, '2017-06-22', 1, 6);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (5571, 3005, '2017-06-22', 1, 7);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3578, 3067, '2017-09-21', 7, 1);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3579, 3067, '2017-09-21', 7, 2);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3621, 3067, '2017-09-21', 7, 3);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3661, 2905, '2017-03-15', 7, 2);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3846, 2905, '2017-03-15', 7, 3);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (4165, 3067, '2017-09-21', 7, 4);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (4378, 2905, '2017-03-15', 7, 4);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (4704, 3251, '2018-03-27', 99, 1);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (4705, 3251, '2018-03-27', 99, 2);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (4706, 3251, '2018-03-27', 99, 3);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (4707, 3251, '2018-03-27', 99, 4);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (4708, 3251, '2018-03-27', 99, 5);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (4735, 3251, '2018-03-27', 99, 6);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (4845, 2905, '2017-03-15', 7, 5);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (5142, 3251, '2018-03-27', 99, 7);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (5415, 3067, '2017-09-21', 7, 5);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (5416, 3067, '2017-09-21', 7, 6);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (5588, 3251, '2018-03-27', 99, 8);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (5589, 3251, '2018-03-27', 99, 9);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (5590, 3251, '2018-03-27', 99, 10);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (5591, 3251, '2018-03-27', 99, 11);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (5891, 2905, '2017-03-15', 7, 6);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (6007, 3362, '2018-09-18', 19, 0);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (6008, 3362, '2018-09-18', 19, 1);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (6045, 3362, '2018-09-18', 19, 2);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (6061, 3251, '2018-03-27', 99, 12);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (6097, 3251, '2018-03-27', 99, 13);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (6554, 3251, '2018-03-27', 99, 14);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (6555, 3251, '2018-03-27', 99, 15);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3042, 3010, '2017-07-10', 0, 1);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3043, 3010, '2017-07-10', 19, 2);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3047, 3010, '2017-07-10', 19, 3);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3048, 3010, '2017-07-10', 19, 4);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3049, 3010, '2017-07-10', 19, 5);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3066, 3010, '2017-07-10', 19, 6);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3067, 3010, '2017-07-10', 19, 7);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3073, 2968, '2017-05-08', 19, 2);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3074, 2968, '2017-05-08', 19, 3);
INSERT INTO `dat_optherapie` (`ID`, `patID`, `OP1Datum`, `OP1OPVerfahren`, `revision`) VALUES (3075, 2968, '2017-05-08', 19, 4);
```

The table `dat_patient` is used only for the integer field `Testzwecke` which has to be set to `0` for non-test patients. The table `users_benutzer` can be completely omitted here (I leave it in the original code above), it has no meaning. The field `OP1OPVerfahren` in the table `dat_optherapie` is but an integer (could also be a string) value for the respective surgical procedure.

The expected outcome is what I have already outlined within the screenshot uploaded.

Here a simplified example of the SQL query above with :

```
SELECT
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Keine Operation durchgeführt",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "2") AS "Gastric Banding",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "3") AS "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "99") AS "Anderes OP-Verfahren",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe"

FROM database1.dat_patient p
LEFT OUTER JOIN database1.dat_optherapie op ON op.patID = p.ID

WHERE op.OP1Datum BETWEEN "2019-01-01" AND "2019-12-31"
AND p.Testzwecke = 0
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM database1.dat_optherapie op2
    WHERE op2.patID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision
)

UNION ALL

SELECT
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Keine Operation durchgeführt",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "2") AS "Gastric Banding",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "3") AS "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "99") AS "Anderes OP-Verfahren",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe"

FROM database2.dat_patient p
LEFT OUTER JOIN database2.dat_optherapie op ON op.patID = p.ID

WHERE op.OP1Datum BETWEEN "2019-01-01" AND "2019-12-31"
AND p.Testzwecke = 0
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM database2.dat_optherapie op2
    WHERE op2.patID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision
)

UNION ALL

[... many more identical SQL queries for other databases ...]

UNION ALL

SELECT
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Keine Operation durchgeführt",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "2") AS "Gastric Banding",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "3") AS "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "99") AS "Anderes OP-Verfahren",
SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe"

FROM database50.dat_patient p
LEFT OUTER JOIN database50.dat_optherapie op ON op.patID = p.ID

WHERE op.OP1Datum BETWEEN "2019-01-01" AND "2019-12-31"
AND p.Testzwecke = 0
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM database50.dat_optherapie op2
    WHERE op2.patID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision
)

GROUP BY OP1OPVerfahren;
```

This SQL code delivers SUMmed record sets per center, but not over all centers. The latter is what I want to achieve.

Experimentally, I have fiddled some change of the SQL query based on the refined code above:

```
SELECT
SUM("Keine Operation durchgeführt"),
SUM("Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)"),
SUM("Gastric Banding"),
SUM("Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass"),
SUM("Anderes OP-Verfahren"),
SUM("Summe")

FROM (

    SELECT
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Keine Operation durchgeführt",
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)",
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "2") AS "Gastric Banding",
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "3") AS "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass",
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "99") AS "Anderes OP-Verfahren",
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe"

    FROM ods01.dat_patient p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ods01.dat_optherapie op ON op.patID = p.ID

    WHERE op.OP1Datum BETWEEN "2019-01-01" AND "2019-12-31"
    AND p.Testzwecke = 0
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM ods01.dat_optherapie op2
        WHERE op2.patID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision
    )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Keine Operation durchgeführt",
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)",
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "2") AS "Gastric Banding",
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "3") AS "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass",
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "99") AS "Anderes OP-Verfahren",
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe"

    FROM ods02.dat_patient p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ods02.dat_optherapie op ON op.patID = p.ID

    WHERE op.OP1Datum BETWEEN "2019-01-01" AND "2019-12-31"
    AND p.Testzwecke = 0
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM ods02.dat_optherapie op2
        WHERE op2.patID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision
    )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "0") AS "Keine Operation durchgeführt",
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "1") AS "Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)",
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "2") AS "Gastric Banding",
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "3") AS "Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass",
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = "99") AS "Anderes OP-Verfahren",
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE "%") AS "Summe"

    FROM ods03.dat_patient p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ods03.dat_optherapie op ON op.patID = p.ID

    WHERE op.OP1Datum BETWEEN "2019-01-01" AND "2019-12-31"
    AND p.Testzwecke = 0
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM ods03.dat_optherapie op2
        WHERE op2.patID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision
    )

    GROUP BY OP1OPVerfahren

) aftershave

-- GROUP BY OP1OPVerfahren;
```

If I take both the subqueries UNIONed and each subquery separately, they show the correct results. But the SUM on the main SQL query level, i. e. not within the subqueries, shows nothing but "0" for each sum.

Comment: `1 = 1` old SQL habit which mean always `1`, you can safely remove it

Comment: Also you can't mix a non aggregate column (`ub.Krankenhaus AS "Zentrum"`) with aggreged columns in SQL, MySQL allowes these bad syntax unless you are running sql_mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` .. i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide (obfuscated) example data and expected results.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Was gonna say the same thing. Beat me to it.

Comment: Yes, @RaymondNijland, thank you, "1 = 1" I should have replaced by "blah" since this is just a placeholder for further WHERE content. I know about your second interjection, I depicted it here for a better understanding's sake where the centers are differentiated.

Comment: Thank you, @TheImpaler, but it does not solve the core question.

Comment: sarcasm does not help solving the question, we are here to help and stackoverflow has guidelines [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section **Help others reproduce the problem** a image and a text which claims you have 50 databases for 50 centers. does not help us reproducing the problem .. You should ideally normilize those 50 into 1 database using separeting databases on metadata like (`ods01`) is pretty much a SQL anti pattern to use..

Comment: .. To answer your question more or less *"How can I create only one resulting table with all surgeries from all 50 centers SUMmed into it (a SUM over the SUMs)?"*  Make a `VIEW` which uses a `UNION ALL` approach  which queries all databases .or simulate a "materialized view" and update it with triggers or a MySQL event there isn't really a other approach

Comment: There is no sarcasm in my comments, if I say "Thank you" to someone then I mean it, @RaymondNijland, and the "but" introducing my subordinate clause makes that clear.

As for MCVE: I will edit my question and provide for the requested material.

Comment: *"There is no sarcasm in my comments, if I say "Thank you" to someone then I mean it,"* Ok then i totally interpreted that wrong blame the beers on friday evenings

Comment: MySQL <> Oracle.  So which one is this???

Comment: @Eric: MySQL, exclusively (as the heading implies).

Comment: @Eric: I see Tony's correction, but I have not added the "oracle" tag. It must have been from a prior approved edit.

Comment: *"This SQL code delivers SUMmed record sets per center, but not over all centers. The latter is what I want to achieve."* i think you are looking for MySQL's GROUP BY [WITH ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) which can add a total record to the result  see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7uYvB35qu1zYkht1tTuEm5/2)

Comment: Thank you for the demo, @RaymondNijland, and maybe I do not understand this correctly, but what I want is: `database1` has, say, 10 OP1OPVerfahren of type "3", `database2` has 5 of the same type and `database50` has 15; now what I want is a result data set in which I find 10 + 5 + 15 = 35 surgical procedures for OP1OPVerfahren of type "3". Sort of one global sum over all database1 to database50 sums.

Comment: *"Sort of one global sum over all database1 to database50 sums. "* then i assume you will need to copy your query into a derived table (subquery).. something like this `SELECT SUM('Keine Operation durchgeführt'), [, SUM(..)...] FROM ( <your_query_here> ) AS  alias`

Comment: Hello, @RaymondNijland, exactly what I have done but to no avail - the results merely display "0" in every SUM (the subqueries, though, work and display the correct sums).

Comment: Okay, I have edited my question with my experimental SQL query at its end.

Comment: Whether databases or tables, don't have 50 of anything. Instead, fix your schema.

Comment: @Strawberry: I do not understand "fix your schema". Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution after some fiddling with the "", '' and `` characters is as such:

```
SELECT
SUM(`Keine Operation durchgeführt`) AS `No surgery`,
SUM(`Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)`) AS `BIB`,
SUM(`Gastric Banding`) AS `GB`,
SUM(`Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass`) AS `RYGB`,
SUM(`Anderes OP-Verfahren`) AS `Other Surgery`,
SUM(`Summe`) AS `Total`

FROM
(

    SELECT
    COUNT(IF(op.OP1OPVerfahren = 0, 1, NULL)) AS `Keine Operation durchgeführt`,
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = 1) AS `Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)`,
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = 2) AS `Gastric Banding`,
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = 3) AS `Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass`,
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = 99) AS `Anderes OP-Verfahren`,
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE '%') AS `Summe`

    FROM ods01.dat_patient p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ods01.dat_optherapie op ON op.patID = p.ID

    WHERE op.OP1Datum BETWEEN '1950-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
    AND p.Testzwecke = 0
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM ods01.dat_optherapie op2
        WHERE op2.patID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision
    )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
    COUNT(IF(op.OP1OPVerfahren = 0, 1, NULL)) AS `Keine Operation durchgeführt`,
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = 1) AS `Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)`,
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = 2) AS `Gastric Banding`,
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = 3) AS `Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass`,
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = 99) AS `Anderes OP-Verfahren`,
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE '%') AS `Summe`

    FROM ods02.dat_patient p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ods02.dat_optherapie op ON op.patID = p.ID

    WHERE op.OP1Datum BETWEEN '1950-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
    AND p.Testzwecke = 0
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM ods02.dat_optherapie op2
        WHERE op2.patID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision
    )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
    COUNT(IF(op.OP1OPVerfahren = 0, 1, NULL)) AS `Keine Operation durchgeführt`,
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = 1) AS `Bioenterics Intragastric Ballon (BIB)`,
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = 2) AS `Gastric Banding`,
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = 3) AS `Roux-en-Y Gastric Bypass`,
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren = 99) AS `Anderes OP-Verfahren`,
    SUM(op.OP1OPVerfahren LIKE '%') AS `Summe`

    FROM ods03.dat_patient p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ods03.dat_optherapie op ON op.patID = p.ID

    WHERE op.OP1Datum BETWEEN '1950-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
    AND p.Testzwecke = 0
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM ods03.dat_optherapie op2
        WHERE op2.patID = p.ID AND op2.revision > op.revision
    )

) whatever;
```

The COUNT(...) statement here shows only that it is equivalent to SUM(...) - the results are the same, I could even have used the COUNT(...) statement for all sums within the subquery.

I thank all of you who tried to help me solving the issue.